# How do you pull customer data from Paypal?

Tags: api, paypal, oauth, paypal-sandbox

What is the right procedure for pulling data about a customer (using OAuth to "Connect with Paypal" similar to the functionality that Stripe and Square provide) from Paypal?

The paypal documentation is confusing in two ways -

1. The OAuth [scopes](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/reference/#scope-attributes) shown only have basic profile information like email, address, name, etc. and the link to the attributes page in the Account Information line item seems broken.
2. Other places mention that you have to sign onto the Paypal partner program to pull data on behalf of third parties.

So, for anyone that has gone through this - what is the right way to proceed/do I have to sign up to Paypal partner program? Is [Permissions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/permissions-service/ht-permissions-invoice/) the right API to use?

I know broadly that connecting and fetching paypal account data is possible since, for example, Kabbage allows you to link your Paypal account and pulls data from it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Connect with PayPal is so a user can click the CwPP button, sign into PayPal agreeing to give you access to certain profile information (based on the selected scopes) -- and then once they grant that permission and return, you're able to use the provided authorization code to access their profile information with its API.

In order to use CwPP in the live environment, your CwPP app has to be approved. You don't need to be in the PayPal partner program for this.

Comment: Yeah so the scopes shown in the link I have mentioned in my question only allow access to basic profile information. What if I want to access actual account data?

Comment: It's not a broken link like your question says, the URI there is the scope's actual string "value".  I'm not sure what account data you're looking for; that link has a complete list of what you can get with CwPP.

Comment: Great, thanks - I didn't think about it like that; I'll try out what you've suggested!